# Gdb symbol lookup error

Tags: 12.04, python-2.7, gdb

I'm trying to use gdb on ubuntu 12.04, but every time the program crashes with the following error

```
gdb: symbol lookup error: gdb: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromEncodedObject
```

Looks something Python related, but I do not know what to do...

Answer (score 1):

Again I will answer myself to my own question for the sake of others:

the error was tied to an incorrect PATH, by typing

```
which python
```

the command returned a path which was NOT the system default python path.

Gdb looks for the default python installation so, in my case, was enough to comment out a source path command in my .bashrc which was overriding the /usr/bin/python path in PATH.

Answer (score 1):

And just like Mutewinter I add my own answer to problem:

A custom specification of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, needed for the project I was supposed to debug, caused the problem. If `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` contains another version of `libpython`, gdb may link in the wrong version causing the symbol error.

You can check which version of `libpython` gdb will use using the following command:

```
ldd /usr/bin/gdb
```

Kind regards, Erik

Answer (score 0):

Your can download python2.6 source code such as

https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.8/Python-2.6.8.tar.bz2

https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.8/Python-2.6.8.tar.bz2.asc

extract and install

```
gpg --verify Python-2.6.8.tar.bz2.asc 
tar -xvf  Python-2.6.8.tar.bz2 
cd Python-2.6.8
./configure --enable-shared --enable-ipv6 --enable-unicode=ucs4 --with-system-ffi --with-threads
make -j5
make install
```